# Formula in a triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Let $H$ be the orthocenter in a triangle with sides $a, b, c$. Is it true that 
$$a^2 + HA^2 = 4R^2$$ where $R$ is the circumradius?

Comment: I put the proof in your last post.

Comment: Oh I see it now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

We consider $B'$reflection of $H$ versus midpoint of $AC$. Because $AHCB'$is parallelogram results that $CB'$ parallel with $AH$ and has the same length. Consequently the triangle $BCB'$ is rectangle and $BB'$ is the diameter of the circumscribed circle. Clear $BC^2+ HA^2=BB'^2$ and $ a^2 + HA^2 =4R^2$.

Comment: Is it clear that $B'$ is on the circumcircle? Or that $B'$ lies on the line $BO$, with $O$ the circumcenter?

Comment: $ABCB'$ is inscriptibil quadrilateral  with angles $BAB'$ and $BCB'$ with measure equal to $90^o$ and then $B'$ is on the circle..

Comment: The angle $B'CB$ is right angle as $B'C$ is parallel to $AH$, but it is not obvious that $B'$ lies on the circle.

Comment: inscriptibil quadrilateral=inscribed quadriteral=concyclic quadrilateral= cyclic_quadrilateral  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_quadrilateral